# jquery load content via ajax and animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am loading in page content via ajax, I am wanting the old content to slide up to the top dissapear, and the new content to follow it into position, my problem is that I cannot seem to get the new content to animate, it just renders on the button click (the old content does however animate). Below is my javascript,

```
$("#ajax").live("click", function(e){
    var loadURL = $(this).attr('href');
    $("#information").animate{{positionTop : "-900px" }, 1000);
    $(".content").load(loadURL + " #information").animate({positionTop: "0px"}, 1000);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Here is my HTML markup,

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="loading"></div>
    <article id="information">
        <header>
            <h1 class="beta"></h1>
            <a href="" class="learn">Learn More</a>
        </header>
        <section class="advantage">

        </section>
        <section class="advantage">

        </section>
        <section class="advantage">

        </section>
        <a class="next-advantage" id="ajax" href="/logic-combi.php">Logic+ Combi</a>
    </article>
</div>
```

The JS is requesting exactly the same setup of HTML, but only from `<article id="information">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform the animation in the callback of the load function.

```
$(".content").load(loadURL + " #information", function(){
  $('#information').animate({positionTop: "0px"}, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Perfect. It really helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

`positionTop` isn't a valid paramater for animate, you may want to use `scrollTop`.